# Facebook - How to force re-scrape on every request?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook usually caches every incoming OpenGraph request and does not scrape again for subsequent requests to that particular URL.
However, commenting/posting the URL to some websites always shows a different image preview. 
How do these services force Facebook to constantly re-scrape them?

One simple way would be to issue a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com` with the `'id' => 'endpoint_url', 'scrape' => true` parameters on specific interval. Is there a way, anyhow, a way to avoid this and ask Facebook to re-scrape every time?

Comment: no, there is no other way. you should try to avoid this anyway and aim for static open graph data.

Comment: Just share unique URLs